# sharex and sharey not creating shared axis labels for subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

My charts are ok, and I've followed documentation to create shared x and y labels since I want a cleaner subplot, but the parameters passed to `subplots()` aren't working correctly.

Code:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10,10))

plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.title('20 highest paid app markets, april 4/4-4/10')
dd_404_410.groupby('market').period_paid_apps.mean().sort_values(ascending=False).nlargest(10).plot(kind='bar', color='darkgrey')
plt.ylabel('apps')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
plt.title('20 highest paid app markets, april 4/11-4/17')
dd_411_417.groupby('market').period_paid_apps.mean().sort_values(ascending=False).nlargest(10).plot(kind='bar', color='darkgrey')
plt.ylabel('apps')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
plt.title('20 highest paid app markets, april 4/18-4/26')
plt.ylabel('apps')
dd_418_426.groupby('market').period_paid_apps.mean().sort_values(ascending=False).nlargest(10).plot(kind='bar', color='darkgrey')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Does anyone know what needs to be fixed so that I have one `market` label on the x axis, and one `apps` label on the y axis?

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed initially created subplots with shared x and y using `plt.subplots()`. But then you are overwriting the axes with the successive commands `plt.subplot()` (notice the lack of *s* at the end).

This is the way you should probably do it (not tested since I don't have your data)

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10,10))

ax1.set_title('20 highest paid app markets, april 4/4-4/10')
ax1.set_ylabel('apps')
<YOUR DATAFRAME>.plot(kind='bar', color='darkgrey', ax=ax1)

ax2.set_title('20 highest paid app markets, april 4/11-4/17')
ax2.set_ylabel('apps')
<YOUR DATAFRAME>.plot(kind='bar', color='darkgrey', ax=ax2)

ax3.set_title('20 highest paid app markets, april 4/18-4/26')
ax3.set_ylabel('apps')
<YOUR DATAFRAME>.plot(kind='bar', color='darkgrey', ax=ax3)

plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```